# Python: await the outer most async function

Tags: python, promise, async-await, python-asyncio, coroutine

Python coroutine created with 'async' keyword (Python 3.5+) can be awaited, however, the outer most one can't be awaited as Python says **"SyntaxError: 'await' outside function"**

```
import asyncio as aio

async def f():
    print(1)
    await aio.sleep(3)
    print(2)
    return 3

print(await f())
```

How to 'await' the 'f' function in the example above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Python 3.7+, the syntax is even simpler (no need to manually create a loop etc.):

```
import asyncio as aio

async def f():
    print(1)
    await aio.sleep(3)
    print(2)
    return 3

print(aio.run(f())
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to await at global scope, instead, run an event loop as below:

```
import asyncio as aio

async def f():
    print(1)
    await aio.sleep(3)
    print(2)
    return 3

def fdone(r):
    print(r.result())

loop = aio.get_event_loop()
t = loop.create_task(f())
t.add_done_callback(fdone)
loop.run_until_complete(t)
print(4)
```

Comment: A simpler `print(loop.run_until_complete(f()))` would work just as well, as`run_until_complete()` will automatically create the task. You don't need `add_done_callback` because `run_until_complete()` returns the result of the awaitable it received.